# Is it possible to use React Navigation with snack.expo.io?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I like to use snack.expo.io because I'm new to programming and it makes it quick and easy to manage and access what I'm working on. However, I just tried to use React Navigation and can't get it to work. I keep getting "Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation.js'. I pulled up the React Navigation snacks at https://expo.io/snacks/@react-navigation and most of those have the same error. Am I missing something?

---

Perhaps my initial question should have asked if there is some initialization step I'm missing. I know I have to import it with something like

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

But is there a dependency I have to manually add? I thought Expo took care of that sort of thing for you, but again, I'm not super experienced with all of this.

Comment: The drawer ones work, can you share a link of a snack that is not working ?

Comment: Probably the Snack you tried to use is "too old" and you should've seen this message: "This Snack was written in an older Expo version that is not longer supported. We have upgraded the Expo version to 37.0.0. You might need to do some manual changes to make the Snack work correctly.". But yes, Snack works with React Navigation

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan https://expo.io/snacks/@react-navigation is what I am looking at. Basic drawer v1 worked, Basic drawer v2 did not. The difference I noticed between them is v1 has a react-navigation dependency in package.json while v2 does not.

Comment: @RafaelTavares, you are correct, it does pop up that message but I must have missed it because it goes away in a second or two. I wish they had something that persisted. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the correct way, but I managed to get past the "unable to resolve" problem. I welcome a better solution from someone more knowledgeable than myself.

It did come down to a dependency issue. Again, in the past I'm pretty sure writing the import line resulted in Snack automatically handling the appropriate dependencies, but for some reason it did not here. So in order to get the React Navigation bottom tab navigator to show up I added

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "latest",
```

to my package.json. My import line had to adjust to

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
```

This came from me poking around the Tab navigation page on reactnavigation.org (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/) Interestingly enough, that did result in Snack pulling in a couple of other dependencies on app reload. I have no clue what the @ in front of react-navigation does; it's the first time I've run into it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set their dependencies in `package.json` and it should work fine:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I figured that was the problem, but I could not find the latest version - or at least a working version - list anywhere. I googled and looked on their website and found nothing indicating the version history so I wasn't sure what to put. I know it has to exist somewhere, so please do share if you know how to find it. As I mentioned in my answer previously, I was able to find more current versions by digging through the other examples on the react navigation website. Apparently that page I listed in the question is just some long forgotten page with outdated information.